# bootstrap inverse navbar displays as normal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Take a [look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PI4df.png) at this inverse navbar's drop down.
Is there a way to keep the styling? Just in case it is my code here is my navbar code: (I can't get html to not show up as html) So here is a [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c24aj.png) 
`<html>`

```
  <code><div class="container-fluid">
        <div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="aHome.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="aResults.html">Results</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Students
                    <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
                        <li><a href="output.php">All users</a></li>
                        <li><a href="deletePlayer.html">Delete User</a></li>
                        <li><a href="editPhone.html">Edit User</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li> 
                <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!--end container-fluid--></code>
```

Comment: You need to post your actual code [mcve] and see the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

Comment: It won't let me put html in here. Hence the photo link.

Comment: This should help http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: `<li class="dropdown-menu">` should be `<li class="dropdown">`, dropdown-menu is only applied to the `ul`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@vanburen answered. I don't know how to mark that comment as an answer. I needed

```
  <li class="dropdown">
```

instead of:

```
  <li class="dropdown-menu">
```